# How to determine if a programming language is verbose or terse?

Tags: programming-languages, readability

Programming languages can often be described as **verbose** or **terse**.

From my understanding, a verbose language is easy to read and understand, while a terse language is concise and neat, but more difficult to read. *Should there be other things to consider in the definitions?*

It seems much of the popular programming languages of today are verbose, and these two terms are only used to describe a language as being more or less, relative to another language.

*How do we determine if a programming language is more verbose/terse over another?*

Example: Is C# more verbose than Java?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> From my understanding, a verbose language is easy to read and understand, while a terse language is concise and neat, but more difficult to read.

This is false.  Verbose means lots of symbols.  Terse means fewer symbols.

This has **nothing** to do with ease of reading or ease of understanding.

Some folks find verbose COBOL easy to read, other find it confusing because so many symbols are required to do so little.

Some folks find terse I/J/K and APL easy to read because the program is very short.  Others find it hard to read because the symbols are obscure.

Terse/Verbose has no relationship with easy to read or easy to understand.

> Should there be other things to consider in the definitions?

No.  The definitions of terse and verbose are fine.

What's important is that these definitions have nothing to do with "easy to read and understand"

> It seems much of the popular programming languages of today are verbose.

Really?

> How do we determine if a programming language is more verbose/terse over another?

Count tokens to get something done.

```
Add 2 TO A GIVING B.
```

7 tokens

```
b = a + 2;
```

6 tokens

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/verbose

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/terse

Comment: +1 for "Terse/Verbose has no relationship with easy to read or easy to understand." I always think of mathematical notation which, when properly done, is remarkably dense yet still relatively readable.

Comment: The example I would use is Python.  Substantially less verbose than C#.  Yet it generally gets great kudos for readability.

Comment: +1 Never thought about it this way. Ease of read/understand seems to be what's implied, but I think this seems to be what verbose/terse really is in programming languages. Can you supply a link for this definition of verbose/terse being symbols? My Google-fu isn't returning me good results.

Comment: @sunpech: That's what the English words mean.  "verbose" means a lot of words.  "terse" means fewer words.  Nothing to do with readability.  Simply word counts.  All I did was replace "word" with "token".  It's just English, nothing special.

Comment: We might also consider the length of the tokens.  Common Lisp looks wordy because so many of the keywords are long, and that also adds to the verboseness of COBOL.

Comment: @Frank Shearar: Absolutely untrue, think about the time it takes for students to learn mathematics. It's as unreadable as it can get (serious mathematics) and even after 6 years of secondary education the majority still are unable to seriously read it. Not that being unreadable is a bad thing! But saying that mathematics is a readable notation is a shortsighted comment ot say the least.

Comment: @DavidMulder: Mathematical notation varies wildly, so I suspect we're both committing sins of hyperbole. Surely you consider the notation for algebra, set theory, basic calculus to be transparent? On the other hand, I consider tensors' abstract notation to be unreadable nonsense. (But then, I also didn't take the time to learn the notation properly.)

Comment: @Frank Shearar: The very basics are so readable to us because they are so normal for us. For example, awhile ago I taught the very basics of algebra to a girl and the very concept of it was alien to her and thus as opaque as possible whereas verbose examples where every x and y is replaced with apples and pears and the entire thing is written out (a lot less efficient and a lot more verbose) she had no trouble the understand the 'equation' and once that concept 'clicks' algebra is by far superior (just like a verbose language isn't always better than a terse one) but to call maths readable...

Comment: @DavidMulder: "1 + 2 = 3" versus "the sum of one and two is equal to three". Which requires less effort to read? I can totally understand someone being utterly confused by the _concepts_ in algebra, but that's not the same thing at all. That would be like claiming that a particular programming language is unreadable because recursion's hard.

Comment: @Frank Shearer: Taken that we aren't talking about concepts (which I think are part of whether a language and notation is readable or not) than "1 + 2 = 3" would simply be "one plus two is equal to three" which is definitely as easy to read (the concept of summing is not the same as addition and addition is a concept common to real life). Secondly, it's about "more readable" not "less _effort_ to read". (A long sentence takes effort to read, though it might be simpler to understand) A good terse notation takes less effort to read *once you are used to it*, yet might be unreadable initially.

Comment: @DavidMulder: I said that _you_ were conflating concepts: "I taught the very basics of algebra to a girl and the very concept of it was alien to her". We're converging on common ground though: you disagreed with my "maths notation is easy to read because it's terse" because that requires one to know how to read it. Fair enough. I regard it as a precondition to "it is readable/unreadable" that one has learned the notation. A _good_ notation combines info density with transparency, and my own opinion is that a lot of maths notation does just that.

Answer (score 6):

> How do we determine if a programming language is more verbose/terse over another?

By comparing the equivalent or similar language constructs, specifically how the same or equivalent task can be solved in one language vs the other.

> Is C# more verbose than Java?

Java is in general more verbose than C#. The most obvious differences include delegates and lambda expressions, where Java requires defining, subclassing and instantiating a distinct interface in order to achieve what is possibly done using a single lambda expression in C#.

Comment: **Java now supports lambda expressions with Java 8** (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: @shanraisshan: yes, it got better over time, but AFAIK Java is still a little bit more verbose. For example, in the docs you linked to, the code contains lots of `p.getAge()` statements. In C#, I would create a property `Age`, which brings the same degree of encapsulation as a member function `getAge`, but makes it possible to write `p.Age` instead.

Comment: Also, while Java has improved, C# hasn't exactly been a static target either ... New features since this answer like generator functions and async/await also serve to allow C# code to be shorter than Java equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

Give a code snippet to non-programmer and ask him/her to explain what that snippet trying to do.
If you get closest answer, then it is verbose. if you get WTF expression then it is terse.

Comment: A terse language will look like a monkey has been randomly bashing keys on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

The measure is called [**expressiveness**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages#Expressiveness) of the language. The typical metric for this is measuring standardized lines of code or statements needed to implement same functionality.

Some values from the Wiki -- how many statements/lines of C code does it take to implement one functionality of one statement/line in:

- C  -- statements: 1 lines: 1
- C++ -- statements: 2.5 lines: 1
- Fortran -- statements: 2.5 lines: 0.8
- Java -- statements: 2.5 lines: 1.5
- Perl -- statements: 6 lines: 6
- Smalltalk -- statements: 6 lines: 6.25
- Python -- statements: 6 lines: 6.5

Comment: I think the fact that one of these measurements suggests that FORTRAN is more expressive than C by some margin (!) while the other states the opposite while stating that C++ is equally expressive to C (!!) sums up the usefulness of such "metrics".

Answer (score -1):

Swift is very terse and readable. COBOL is very verbose and I find it hard to read. You need to use a language in real life and decide. And “readable” depends on how much you are used to it.